# Mendix Validation Check with existing record

Tags: mendix

Currently I'm working on a project which related to an entity which is **Shift** and the attributes are **ID, Name and Description**. I will require to **add, edit and delete the shift record**. May I know how is the validation logic performed in microflow **to compare with existing record in database, and show the record is already existed if the record is existed**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out for yourself which of these attributes, or a combination of those, is unique. Since you have a shift ID, it sounds like this one is unique. Do a retrieve from database on ID = $Shift/ID. If the database retrieve works and retrieves a shift, it already exists in the database and you can show a warning. If the retrieve's result is empty, you know it didn't exist yet.